# tomcat is logging all the tomcat related Debug logs

Tags: linux, tomcat, logging, logback

I have changed my tomcat logging to use logback.xml instead of util.Logger. I have changed using mentioned steps on https://github.com/grgrzybek/tomcat-slf4j-logback.
But now on starting tomcat it is logging every Debug log of tomcat.
My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
<pattern>
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{20}] : %msg%n
</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-CATALINA" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<encoder>
<charset>utf-8</charset>
<pattern>
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{40}] : %msg%n
</pattern>
</encoder>
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>
${catalina.base}/logs/catalina-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip
</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>
60
<!--  days  -->
</maxHistory>
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-LOCALHOST" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<encoder>
<charset>utf-8</charset>
<pattern>
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n
</pattern>
</encoder>
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>
${catalina.base}/logs/localhost-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip
</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>
60
<!--  days  -->
</maxHistory>
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-MANAGER" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/manager.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<encoder>
<charset>utf-8</charset>
<pattern>
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n
</pattern>
</encoder>
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>
${catalina.base}/logs/manager-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip
</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>
60
<!--  days  -->
</maxHistory>
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-HOST-MANAGER" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<encoder>
<charset>utf-8</charset>
<pattern>
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n
</pattern>
</encoder>
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>
${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip
</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>
60
<!--  days  -->
</maxHistory>
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="INFO" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="FILE-LOCALHOST"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="FILE-MANAGER"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="FILE-HOST-MANAGER"/>
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

> Logs are like this 
>   07:16:09.218 [main] DEBUG o.a.tomcat.util.digester.Digester -   Fire end() for SetNextRule[methodName=addLifecycleListener, paramType=org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener]
>   07:16:09.218 [main] DEBUG o.a.tomcat.util.digester.Digester - [SetNextRule]{Server/Listener} Call org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.addLifecycleListener(org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener@277b8705)

---

This is line coming when I am starting tomcat :

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /mnt/production/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /mnt/production/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /mnt/production/apache-tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/bitnami/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /mnt/production/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/mnt/production/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

So classpath looks correct to me.

Comment: Have you removed `TOMCAT/conf/logging.properties` file? I have these DEBUG messages when I forget to do so...

Comment: Yes I have removed logging.properties.

Comment: I have removed logback.xml and started. It is doing same.

Comment: You should not remove `logback.xml`. Do you have `TOMCAT/bin/setenv.sh` file with `LOGGING_MANAGER=-Dnop
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:$CATALINA_HOME/conf/logback.xml"`?

Comment: Fixed by adding lines in setenv.sh

LOGGING_MANAGER=-Dnop
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:$CATALINA_HOME/conf/logback.xml"